# contenteditable is triggering blur on parent

Tags: javascript, html

Situation that I have:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child" contenteditable="true"></div>
</div>
```

Parent div have blur eventListener.
Every time I click inside contenteditable child, blur is triggered on parent.

If I preventDefault mousedown on contenteditable, then I can't edit it.

How can I edit text in contenteditable child without triggering blur on parent?

Comment: You can check [e.target](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target) to find out which element dispatched the event

Comment: Only one element can be focussed at a time. Just like an `<input>`, a `contenteditable` element must be focussed before you can enter text. Therefore the previously focussed element is automatically blurred (“unfocussed”). That said, there are some interesting workarounds in the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37054885/1813169).

Comment: @AlonEitan e.target for blur is always parent div so that doesn't help much

Comment: @MTCoster so combo of any input and blur on parent can't work at all?

Comment: What’s the significance of the `blur` on your parent `<div>`?

Comment: @MTCoster parent is a popup modal that contains URL, and I want to enable editing that url

Comment: Please add a [mcve] as the "situation" you posted does not reproduce your problem.

Comment: You should probably use a custom event to trigger the modal dismiss if you want the modal to be interactive, otherwise even just hitting tab will be enough to dismiss it.

Comment: @MTCoster I'm thinking to test active element in blur function, and if is contenteditable, skip blur code...can't test it currently

Comment: @WolfWar Please show us your JS and proper HTML that demonstrate the issue, because it is working as expected [here](http://jsfiddle.net/gk2tnfdr/)

Comment: @AlonEitan can't currently....and your parent never triggers blur...only child element, that is not the case here...I don't need child blur

Comment: @WolfWar I know, that's why I asked you to create a [mcve] that demonstrate the issue because I wasn't able to reproduce it with the details you provided. I need to know more before I can help